# Filter a list of item, Sort and Group By with jQuery

Tags: jquery, sorting, filtering

I'm in trouble trying to build a complex filtering system.

I have links that filter a long list of items. The filters work, but I don't know how to use the load more function together with the filters.

- On all filters except "ALL", I need to add more items which belong to the same "category" (data-filter). For the moment, it adds more items but not from the corresponding data-filter.
- If I click on "ALL" filter, the load more button should add three new
  groups of letter..For example if I display A, B, C, it must show
  D,E,F; (and corresponding items)..

For the moment, here is what I have :

```js
$('.suppliers-alphabet').hide();
$(".populaires").slice(0, 3).addClass('active');
    $('.filters .nav li a').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        
        var activeClass = $(this).data('filter');
        $(this).addClass('active');
        $('.filters .nav li').removeClass('active');
        $(this).parent().toggleClass('active');
    
       if(activeClass == 'all') {
            $('.suppliers-alphabet').show();
            $('.suppliers-list').children('div.suppliers-list--row').addClass('active').sort(function(a, b) {
                var aText = $(a).text(), bText = $(b).text();
                return aText < bText ? -1 : aText > bText ? 1 : 0;
            }).appendTo('.suppliers-list');
            
            $('.suppliers-list--row').each(function () {
                var letter = $('.supplier-name', this).text().charAt(0);
                if ($(this).parent().find('[data-letter="'+ letter +'"]').length>0) {
                    $(this).parent().find('[data-letter="'+ letter +'"]').remove();
                }else{
                    $(this).before('<h4 data-letter="'+ letter+'" id="'+ letter.toLowerCase() + '" class="supplier-alphabet--letter">'+ letter +'</h4>').slice(0, 3);
                }     
                
            });
            
        }else{
            $('.suppliers-list').children('div:not(.' + activeClass + ')').removeClass('active');
            $('.suppliers-list').children('div.' + activeClass).slice(0, 3).addClass('active');
            
            $('.suppliers-alphabet').hide();
            $('.suppliers-list').find('.supplier-alphabet--letter').detach();
            
            $("#load_more a").show();
            $("#load_more a").on('click', function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                
                $('.suppliers-list').children('div.' + activeClass).filter(':hidden').slice(0, 3).addClass('active');
                if ($('.suppliers-list').children('div.' + activeClass).filter(':hidden').length === 0) {
                    $("#load_more a").fadeOut('slow');
                }
                $('html,body').animate({
                    scrollTop: $(this).offset().top
                }, 100);
            });
        }
    
        return false;
    });
```

```css
.suppliers-list--row {
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #F9F9F9;
    padding: 10px 3px;
    height: 45px;
    display:none;
}
.suppliers-list--row.active{
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
}
.supplier-name {
    font-size: 1.143em;
    display: inline-block;
}

.suppliers-links {
    margin-left: auto;
}

.suppliers-featured {
    margin: 1em 0 3.125em 0;
}

.suppliers-alphabet {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-pack: justify;
    -ms-flex-pack: justify;
    justify-content: space-between;
    width: 80%;
    margin: 20px 0;
    -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    line-height: 1.5;
}

.suppliers-alphabet a {
    color: #0070C0;
    font-size: 1.286em;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin-right: 7px;
}

.suppliers-list {
    padding: 20px 6px;
    margin-bottom: 1.5em;
}

.suppliers-list--row:first-of-type,
.suppliers-list--row:last-of-type{
    padding-top:20px;
}

.suppliers-alphabet a:hover,
.suppliers-alphabet a:focus {
    color: #00537C;
}
.supplier-alphabet--letter {
    color: #0070C0;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.suppliers-list--row a.contact {
    display: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    border-radius: 6px;
    margin-right: 25px;
}
.filters {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    margin: 50px 0 0;
}

.filters .nav {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.filters .nav li {
    margin-bottom: 2em;
    margin-right: 1em;
    position: relative;
}

.filters .nav li a {
    background: #F4F4F4;
    color: #000100;
    border-radius: 11px;
    padding: 7px 20px;
    height: 31px;
    text-decoration: none;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-transition: .3s;
    -o-transition: .3s;
    transition: .3s;
}

.filters .nav li a:hover,
.filters .nav .active a {
    background-color: #0070C0;
    color: #ffffff;
}

.filters .nav li .filter-close {
    display: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: url(../img/icons8-delete@2x.png);
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 0.750em;
    height: 11px;
    margin-right: 8px;
    position: relative;
}

.filters .nav .active .filter-close {
    display: inline-block;
}

.filter-close:hover {
    background: #bbb;
}

#load_more {
    margin: 30px auto;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
        -ms-flex-pack: center;
            justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <div class="filters">
    <ul class="nav">
      <li><a href="#" class="active" data-filter="populaires"><span class="filter-close"></span>recent</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" data-filter="partenaires"><span class="filter-close"></span>related</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" data-filter="hdpe"><span class="filter-close"></span>popular</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" data-filter="ldpe"><span class="filter-close"></span>archived</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" data-filter="lldpe"><span class="filter-close"></span>upcoming</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" data-filter="all"><span class="filter-close"></span>all</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
       
        
  <section>
    <div class="suppliers-featured">
      <img src="img/suppliers_bg@2x.png" alt="" style="width:728px;max-width:100%">
    </div>
    <div class="suppliers-alphabet">
      <a href="#a">A.</a>
      <a href="#b">B.</a>
      <a href="#c">C.</a>
      <a href="#d">D.</a>
      <a href="#e">E.</a>
      <a href="#f">F.</a>
      <a href="#g">G.</a>
      <a href="#h">H.</a>
      <a href="#i">I.</a>
      <a href="#j">J.</a>
      <a href="#k">K.</a>
      <a href="#l">L.</a>
      <a href="#m">M.</a>
      <a href="#n">N.</a>
      <a href="#o">O.</a>
      <a href="#p">P.</a>
      <a href="#q">Q.</a>
      <a href="#r">R.</a>
      <a href="#s">S.</a>
      <a href="#t">T.</a>
      <a href="#u">U.</a>
      <a href="#v">V.</a>
      <a href="#w">W.</a>
      <a href="#x">X.</a>
      <a href="#y">Y.</a>
      <a href="#z">Z.</a>
      </div>
  </section>
  <section>
    <div class="suppliers-list">
      <div class="suppliers-list--row populaires">
        <div class="supplier-name">Brand Name</div>
        <div class="suppliers-links">
          <a class="link contact" href="">Contact the supplier</a>
          <a class="link contact-small" href=""><img src="img/icons-blue-envelope.png" style="width:31px;height:31px" alt=""></a>
          <a class="submit product" href="">See all products</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    <div class="suppliers-list--row partenaires">
      <div class="supplier-name">ABrand Name</div>
      <div class="suppliers-links">
        <a class="link contact" href="">Contact the supplier</a>
        <a class="link contact-small" href=""><img src="img/icons-blue-envelope.png" style="width:31px;height:31px" alt=""></a>
        <a class="submit product" href="">See all products</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="suppliers-list--row populaires">
      <div class="supplier-name">YBrand Name</div>
      <div class="suppliers-links">
        <a class="link contact" href="">Contact the supplier</a>
        <a class="link contact-small" href=""><img src="img/icons-blue-envelope.png" style="width:31px;height:31px" alt=""></a>
        <a class="submit product" href="">See all products</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="suppliers-list--row partenaires">
      <div class="supplier-name">TBrand Name</div>
      <div class="suppliers-links">
        <a class="link contact" href="">Contact the supplier</a>
        <a class="link contact-small" href=""><img src="img/icons-blue-envelope.png" style="width:31px;height:31px" alt=""></a>
        <a class="submit product" href="">See all products</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="suppliers-list--row ldpe">
      <div class="supplier-name">LBrand Name</div>
      <div class="suppliers-links">
        <a class="link contact" href="">Contact the supplier</a>
        <a class="link contact-small" href=""><img src="img/icons-blue-envelope.png" style="width:31px;height:31px" alt=""></a>
        <a class="submit product" href="">See all products</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="suppliers-list--row lldpe">
      <div class="supplier-name">XBrand Name</div>
      <div class="suppliers-links">
        <a class="link contact" href="">Contact the supplier</a>
        <a class="link contact-small" href=""><img src="img/icons-blue-envelope.png" style="width:31px;height:31px" alt=""></a>
        <a class="submit product" href="">See all products</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="suppliers-list--row hdpe">
      <div class="supplier-name">MBrand Name</div>
      <div class="suppliers-links">
        <a class="link contact" href="">Contact the supplier</a>
        <a class="link contact-small" href=""><img src="img/icons-blue-envelope.png" style="width:31px;height:31px" alt=""></a>
        <a class="submit product" href="">See all products</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="suppliers-list--row ldpe">
      <div class="supplier-name">KBrand Name</div>
      <div class="suppliers-links">
        <a class="link contact" href="">Contact the supplier</a>
        <a class="link contact-small" href=""><img src="img/icons-blue-envelope.png" style="width:31px;height:31px" alt=""></a>
        <a class="submit product" href="">See all products</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="suppliers-list--row populaires">
      <div class="supplier-name">LBrand Name</div>
      <div class="suppliers-links">
        <a class="link contact" href="">Contact the supplier</a>
        <a class="link contact-small" href=""><img src="img/icons-blue-envelope.png" style="width:31px;height:31px" alt=""></a>
        <a class="submit product" href="">See all products</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="suppliers-list--row partenaires">
      <div class="supplier-name">ABrand Name</div>
      <div class="suppliers-links">
        <a class="link contact" href="">Contact the supplier</a>
        <a class="link contact-small" href=""><img src="img/icons-blue-envelope.png" style="width:31px;height:31px" alt=""></a>
        <a class="submit product" href="">See all products</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="suppliers-list--row populaires">
      <div class="supplier-name">CBrand Name</div>
      <div class="suppliers-links">
        <a class="link contact" href="">Contact the supplier</a>
        <a class="link contact-small" href=""><img src="img/icons-blue-envelope.png" style="width:31px;height:31px" alt=""></a>
        <a class="submit product" href="">See all products</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="suppliers-list--row partenaires">
      <div class="supplier-name">Brand Name</div>
      <div class="suppliers-links">
        <a class="link contact" href="">Contact the supplier</a>
        <a class="link contact-small" href=""><img src="img/icons-blue-envelope.png" style="width:31px;height:31px" alt=""></a>
        <a class="submit product" href="">See all products</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="suppliers-list--row ldpe">
      <div class="supplier-name">Brand Name</div>
      <div class="suppliers-links">
        <a class="link contact" href="">Contact the supplier</a>
        <a class="link contact-small" href=""><img src="img/icons-blue-envelope.png" style="width:31px;height:31px" alt=""></a>
        <a class="submit product" href="">See all products</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="suppliers-list--row lldpe">
      <div class="supplier-name">EBrand Name</div>
      <div class="suppliers-links">
        <a class="link contact" href="">Contact the supplier</a>
        <a class="link contact-small" href=""><img src="img/icons-blue-envelope.png" style="width:31px;height:31px" alt=""></a>
        <a class="submit product" href="">See all products</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="suppliers-list--row hdpe">
      <div class="supplier-name">FBrand Name</div>
      <div class="suppliers-links">
        <a class="link contact" href="">Contact the supplier</a>
        <a class="link contact-small" href=""><img src="img/icons-blue-envelope.png" style="width:31px;height:31px" alt=""></a>
        <a class="submit product" href="">See all products</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="suppliers-list--row ldpe">
      <div class="supplier-name">EBrand Name</div>
      <div class="suppliers-links">
        <a class="link contact" href="">Contact the supplier</a>
        <a class="link contact-small" href=""><img src="img/icons-blue-envelope.png" style="width:31px;height:31px" alt=""></a>
        <a class="submit product" href="">See all products</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="suppliers-list--row populaires">
      <div class="supplier-name">GBrand Name</div>
      <div class="suppliers-links">
        <a class="link contact" href="">Contact the supplier</a>
        <a class="link contact-small" href=""><img src="img/icons-blue-envelope.png" style="width:31px;height:31px" alt=""></a>
        <a class="submit product" href="">See all products</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="suppliers-list--row partenaires">
      <div class="supplier-name">HBrand Name</div>
      <div class="suppliers-links">
        <a class="link contact" href="">Contact the supplier</a>
        <a class="link contact-small" href=""><img src="img/icons-blue-envelope.png" style="width:31px;height:31px" alt=""></a>
        <a class="submit product" href="">See all products</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="suppliers-list--row populaires">
      <div class="supplier-name">Brand Name</div>
      <div class="suppliers-links">
        <a class="link contact" href="">Contact the supplier</a>
        <a class="link contact-small" href=""><img src="img/icons-blue-envelope.png" style="width:31px;height:31px" alt=""></a>
        <a class="submit product" href="">See all products</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="suppliers-list--row partenaires">
      <div class="supplier-name">Brand Name</div>
      <div class="suppliers-links">
        <a class="link contact" href="">Contact the supplier</a>
        <a class="link contact-small" href=""><img src="img/icons-blue-envelope.png" style="width:31px;height:31px" alt=""></a>
        <a class="submit product" href="">See all products</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="suppliers-list--row ldpe">
      <div class="supplier-name">Brand Name</div>
      <div class="suppliers-links">
        <a class="link link-white contact" href="">Contact the supplier</a>
        <a class="link contact-small" href=""><img src="img/icons-blue-envelope.png" style="width:31px;height:31px" alt=""></a>
        <a class="submit product" href="">See all products</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="suppliers-list--row lldpe">
      <div class="supplier-name">Brand Name</div>
      <div class="suppliers-links">
        <a class="link contact" href="">Contact the supplier</a>
        <a class="link contact-small" href=""><img src="img/icons-blue-envelope.png" style="width:31px;height:31px" alt=""></a>
        <a class="submit product" href="">See all products</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="suppliers-list--row hdpe">
      <div class="supplier-name">Brand Name</div>
      <div class="suppliers-links">
        <a class="link contact" href="">Contact the supplier</a>
        <a class="link contact-small" href=""><img src="img/icons-blue-envelope.png" style="width:31px;height:31px" alt=""></a>
        <a class="submit product" href="">See all products</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="suppliers-list--row ldpe">
      <div class="supplier-name">Brand Name</div>
      <div class="suppliers-links">
        <a class="link contact" href="">Contact the supplier</a>
        <a class="link contact-small" href=""><img src="img/icons-blue-envelope.png" style="width:31px;height:31px" alt=""></a>
        <a class="submit product" href="">See all products</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
     <div id="load_more">
         <a href="#" class="submit product">See more suppliers</a>
  </div>
</section>
```